# Why does $dG < 0$ imply that processes involving chemical reactions are spontaneous?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

Here is a short proof/derivation of why $dG < 0$ implies that a process is spontaneous (for constant temperature and pressure):

[image]

But this derivation assumes that only mechanical work is done on the system. If the process involves chemical changes the expression for internal energy becomes:[image]

With this expression for $dU$ the last step in the derivation no longer holds: since $dG = dQ - TdS + \sum_i \mu_iN_i \neq dQ - TdS$, $dQ < TdS$ is not equivalent to $dG < 0$. It seems to me like there could be a hypothetical process for which $dG < 0$ but where $dQ > TdS$. With a process like that, the total entropy change (the environment plus the system) is negative (i.e. it is impossible). Yet, $dG < 0$ is commonly used by chemists as a criterion for the spontaneity of chemical reactions. What am I missing?

Comment: *Yet, $dG<0$ is commonly used by chemists as a criterion for the spontaneity of chemical reactions.* Note that 'spontaneous' is a very slippery term here. Huge numbers of reactions (including very common ones, like combustions) show $dG<0$, yet will not proceed at RT. As we say: 'thermodynamics says nothing about kinetics'. And if it were otherwise our world would be a very different one.

Comment: What you describe is only a rule of thumb.  It treats a reaction as spontaneous if the equilibrium constant is > 1.  But, if you mix pure reactants for any reaction, the reaction will proceed spontaneously until some products are produced.

Comment: Please do not use images for equations. Use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to enter mathematical 
expressions on Physics SE, as it is the site standard. Images of text or equations 
are very strongly discouraged and can result in downvotes.

Comment: @ChetMiller I believe $dG<0$ still works rigorously in the case you describe, rather than being just a rule of thumb. The first molecule of product—with all of its unique position options—increases entropy tremendously. This drives $dG\equiv d(H-TS)\approx -TdS$ (because $dH$ for a single molecule can be ignored) to be strongly negative.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Are you saying that no significant amount of product will be formed if the equilibrium constant is even the slightest bit less than 1.0?

Comment: I didn't say anything about the equilibrium constant (nor did the question, nor have any of the answers to date).

Comment: @Chemomechanics. You are aware that, if $\Delta G^0<0$ the equilibrium constant is > 1, and if $\Delta G^0>0$ the equilibrium constant is < 1, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this derivation assumes that only mechanical work is done on the system.

The derivation does assume that the only form of work done is PV work. You object that this assumption is invalid if chemical changes occur. But chemical changes are not "work", so this assumption does not undermine the conclusion.

Your expression for $\mathrm{d}U$ is correct, but there is nowhere in the derivation where you can actually use it. It does not imply that $\mathrm{d}U$ is anything other than $\delta Q - P \, \mathrm{d}V$, so the rest of the derivation is still valid.

In effect, you are making a statement about what $U$ is "made of": chemical energy is one of the components. That's true, but this derivation doesn't make any assumptions about what $U$ is made of.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the derivation assumes that only mechanical work can be done on the system, and no transfer of particles and associated energy can happen; it is in the first sentence, "no matter can come in or out".

This does not mean chemical changes inside the system are forbidden; instead, they can happen but they don't affect the fact that the system is closed and don't contradict the assumption that only mechanical work is possible.

So the derivation is correct even if internal changes of chemical composition happen.

On the formal aspect: the derivation uses the expression
$$
dU = dQ - PdV
$$
which is valid due to assumptions. But it does not use your expression for $dU$ in terms of $dS,dV,dN_i$, so there is no problem with the derivation, even if $N_i$ change due to chemical processes.

Answer (score 0):

We have, for the Gibbs free energy $G=\sum_i \mu_i N_i$ for species $i$ with numbers $N_i$ and chemical potentials. For a set of reactions denoted in stoichiometric notation
$$
\sum_i \nu_i X_i -\sum_f \nu_f X_f = 0
$$
and imposing conservation of species: $\frac{dN_i}{\nu_i} = dN = -\frac{dN_f}{\nu_f} = $ constant for all $i$ and $f$, yields
$$
dG = dN \left(\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i - \sum_f \mu_f \nu_f \right).
$$
For reactions that proceed "from left to right"
$$
\sum_i \mu_i \nu_i > \sum_f \mu_f \nu_f.
$$
where $i(f)$ denotes initial (final) reactants. For these reactions $dN<0$, implying $dG<0$.

Comment: This answers seems to [beg the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)—doesn't writing down the reaction to correctly proceed "from left to right" presuppose that $dG<0$?

Comment: You can work out the reverse reaction and get the same result. Try it. The main point is that $dN$ has the opposite sign as the factor it multiplies.

Comment: Only if you've pre-identified the reactants and products, it seems. I don't believe this answer works if given two generic species A and B with no information about which is the stable species at equilibrium. Any inequality you write using $\mu$ relies on $G$ already, as $\mu_i\equiv(\partial G/\partial N_i)$. The point of the original question is to derive $dG<0$ for generic participants in a reaction.

Comment: This derivation for $dG<0$ is completely general. A reaction is defined by a set of reactants and products, so your objection seems strange. Please provide an alternative derivation for comparison.

Comment: I've upvoted the other two answers to date, and one has been accepted by the OP. Neither uses a chemical potential inequality to justify a Gibbs free energy inequality, and I think that's wise, as the chemical potential *is* the partial molar Gibbs free energy—thus my remark on "begging the question."

Comment: I’ve removed a number of inappropriate comments; be kind, please.

Comment: Being kind in my reiteration -- @Chemomechanics, you have not provided an analytic counter-proof or an analytic refutation of the concrete analysis I provided. Try again.